# check whether a library has already been loaded with System.load(...)

Tags: java

In my java program, I loaded a library built from native code by:

```
System.load(PATH_TO_LIB_FILE);
```

I am wondering in Java, how could I check whether this specific library has been loaded already before I execute the above code?

Comment: AFAIK it is safe to (attempt to) load it as ClassLoader will check and will not load it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, load it in a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). You can take advantage of the single instance-ness of the Singleton to ensure that library is loaded once. Similarly, you could have `boolean` flag and check (default to `false`) - if it's true the library has been loaded, otherwise load the library and set the flag to `true`. There are other options, none as elegant (IMO). For example, place the `load` call in a static initializer block in your class, as long as you don't Serialize instances of that class it should ensure that the library is loaded once.